# Windows Phone Store ® Certification Test Results Fail

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

My Windows App reject by the Following reason:

1. Depending on the underlying cause of the issue encountered, the following resources may provide useful guidance to resolve:
   • "Product ID": Avoid hard-coded logic based on the original Product ID. If your application design requires using logic based on a Product
   ID, use the Windows Phone Store assigned non-volatile Product ID instead
2. Data for Windows Phone | Installation folder": Don’t write to the InstalledLocation folder in your production application release
   submitted for certification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx)
3. Capability Detection": Double check that the capabilities required by your application are declared correctly. You can do this by running
   the Windows Phone Capability Detection Tool, as described at How to: Use the Windows Phone Capability Detection Tool
   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730.aspx).
   **Note:** But My app working in my windows phone(Nokia Lumia 510) and Emulator.

I have totally confused what mistake i done in My Application.

Please give a suggestion. I am wating for all reply

Answer (score 0):

Try testing on Windows Phone 8. There's been a few API changes in Windows Phone 8, which may result in failure on some functions, which works well in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is #3 - you're using a capability (data, location, etc) and not declaring it. Your app will still work in the emulator in this case, but will fail certification. Use the tool they mentioned to test this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730.aspx

Comment: Hi Deeko, Thanks for your reply. I have tested in my WMAppManifest.xml. But i declared what this url(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730.aspx) decalared.